# CSS Transition/Animation Not Working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have divs that use a css animation to spin around and have text fade in, these work on mouse hover.
The fade in is working however the spin is not working. Below is my code.

```css
.hover-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.hover-img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>ggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
  <div id="cell1">
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; height: 390px; background-image: url(slide2.png);">ffffffffffff</div>
    <p></p>
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; height: 390px; background-image: url(slide2.png);">ffffffffffff</div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="cell1">
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; height: 390px; background-image: url(slide2.png);">ffffffffffff</div>
    <p></p>
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; height: 390px; background-image: url(slide2.png);">ffffffffffff</div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="cell3">
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; height: 390px; background-image: url(slide2.png);">ffffffffffff</div>
    <p></p>
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; height: 390px; background-image: url(slide2.png);">ffffffffffff</div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also believe as this is a site specific problem it will be helpful to include a [livelink.](http://www.cambridgedesign.company/graphic.html) I will remove it as soon as the question is answered for future posterity of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this fiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8h7vko11/3/)

1:
I changed `-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);` to `-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);`

2:
 I added `transform: rotateY(180deg);` 
3:
I encapsulated `.hover-img` with . `.trigger` so when you hover `.trigger` it will animate the `.hover-img`

I tested it in: Firefox (latest), Chrome(latest) IE(latest)

Comment: just out of curiosity will the .trigger make it work on iPad?